# SOA application dependency

Tags: soa

We have a SOA based applications and there are few dependencies between the applications.
For example we have city codes in the master which is used by other applications.

In the dependant applications  ,is it better to have city code or primary key id of the city record. I feel city code makes more send as business data rather than the id ( which is kind of more coupled ) .

Answer (score 2):

The primary key feels like an implementation detail that's private to the service and the database.  I would not expose that detail to clients of the service.

But it sounds like your city code is a unique field that is *at least* a candidate key.  Why not use *it* as the primary key in this case?

A surrogate key might make sense if there's business logic in the city code that could change.  But if that's not the case, perhaps you could consider it.

Comment: Agree with this answer. Also, you may want to understand if there's a tight coupling between your services and also if there's a possibility to compose your services so that the data is not consumed by services that may not directly need it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a code (e.g 'DUB') and use it as a shared contract across my system, no one service owns this anyway? this way you decouple the dependency and have a more readable, convention based key...

Answer (score 0):

I would use Domain Value Map (DVM) for this purposes. 
Domain value maps operate on actual data values that transit through the infrastructure at runtime. They enable you to map from one vocabulary used in a given domain to another vocabulary used in a different domain